# Complex Convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let a sequnce $z_n$ (n=1,2,..) converge to a number z. Show that there exists a positive number M such that the inequality |$z_n$| $\leq$ M holds for all n. Do this in each of the following ways.

a) Note that there is a positive integer $n_0$ such that |$z_n$| = |$z$ + ($z_n$ - $z$)|$<$ |$z$| + 1 whenever $n$>$n_0$

Hints are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$z_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}z\stackrel{\text{definition}}\iff \;\forall\,\epsilon >0\;\exists N\in\Bbb N\;\;\;s.t\;\;\;\;n>N\implies |z_n-z|<\epsilon$$

The above is only the definition of convergence in $\;\Bbb C\;$ . Now apply this with $\;\epsilon=1\;$ and use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: You should take a look at the definition of complex convergence.
Hint 2: You probably have proven a similar thing for sequences in $\mathbb R$.